# How to configure gatsby-plugin-google-analytics with cookies consent?

Tags: google-analytics, gatsby

I have developed a website using `gatsby` and I am using google analytics plugin via `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`, now to be nice with the users, I would like to add a cookie consent where the user will be two options whether to accept or decline cookies usages. If the user declines then I would like to stop google analytics to track the user activity. I dug into their documentation but unable to find the option to achieve this, is there any way around to achieve this.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
  options: {
    trackingId: siteConfig.googleAnalyticsId,
    // Defines where to place the tracking script - `true` in the head and `false` in the body
    head: false,
  },
},
```

For the movement my `gatsby-config.js` looks like this. how one can achieve this.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin merely loads the library and instruments page tracking calls in a Gatsby-compatible way for you. All of the other Google Analytics calls, including [disabling measurement for a user](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1LHZ4rkrudsJ:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us#opt-out_of_measurement_for_your_site) works the same as normal.

It's up to you to:

1. Build and show a cookie notice with an opt-out
2. Remember when a user has opted out
3. Communicate this on each page-load for the user (before any `ga()` calls are made) by setting `window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true`

You should be able to do this in a function exported as [`onClientEntry`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry) from `gatsby-browser.js`. For example:

```js
export const onClientEntry = () => {
  if (userHasOptedOutOfThirdPartyTracking()) {
    window[`ga-disable-${process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID`] = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Gatsby website, you could use a combination of [`gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/) for analytics cookies management in your `gatsby-config.js` and [`react-cookie-consent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent) to display the cookie banner.

```sh
# using npm
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies react-cookie-consent

# using yarn
yarn add gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies react-cookie-consent
```

You can find a more detailed tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860068/how-set-up-a-gatsby-cookie-consent-banner-with-gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/59922277#59922277).